# How to reload environment variable in shell script without restarting Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to set a environment variable globally for all users in linux.

In order to do that I modified /etc/environment file.

For example at the end of file.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "\nmyenv=hello" >> /etc/environment'
```

After executing this command when in run in the same terminal.

```
echo $myenv
```

i'm not getting the value hello.

After typing the below command.

```
source /etc/environment
```

I'm able to access the environment variable in command prompt with

```
echo $myenv
```

But the problem in this method is if i execute a sh file. Which is accessing the $myenv. I need to again type the command
source /etc/environment in that shell script.

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Please suggest me what is the approach followed here.

I don't what to logoff and logon or restart my server.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is parsed by `pam_env`.

Answer (score 2):

An environment variable is only inherited by child processes if it is **exported**.

```
myenv=hello
export myenv
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , So where i need to type this command. Because sudo sh -c 'echo "\nmyenv=hello" >> /etc/environment' is done by one script and it is accessed by another script.

Comment: Actually don't put this *precise* syntax in `/etc/environment` because it is shared with other shells. Instead, add `export myenv` on a separate line.

Comment: @tripleee Can yo please  provide me with some examples. Please find the explanation. I have a script which is creating an environment variable. This environment variable is added to /etc/environment. Because i want this for different users. Now from this script if i'm invoking a child process i need to write export myenv=hello after adding it to environment file. But in my case i'm manually execute the same script again in the same terminal. So I want to check the environment variable there on the second execution of batch script.

Comment: John's answer is basically correct and explains how to achieve this. My comment pertains to tweaking the syntax so it doesn't only work with Bash; this file will need to usable by other Bourne-compatible shells like Dash etc too. Once you have the `export` there you can `source` this file from your current shell (or even from the soript which just added it, though that will obviously only affect the script's own environment).